# How to do Threading in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading, jquery-ui, progress-bar

So I have a large JSON object i'm returning from the server, then building a datatable from it and displaying it on the form. This usually takes a few seconds.. so I was thinking of a loading bar. 
I have the logic behind the loading bar, however the loop that builds the hmtl data is locking down the browser and I cannot call out to the element i need to update.

Here is my function to do this:

```
function buildDataTable(db_table, container_id) {
    var $pb = $("<div id=\"progress-bar\"></div>");
    $(container_id).html($pb);
    $pb.progressbar({
        value: 0
    });
    $.post("post location", {
        view: "all"
    }, function (data) {
        var headers = "";
        var contents = "";
        var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(data);
        var tik = Math.round(jsonObject.length / 100);
    for (key in jsonObject[0]) {
            headers += "<th>" + key.replace(" ", "&nbsp;") + "</th>";
        }
        for (i in jsonObject) {
            contents += "<tr>";
            for (j in jsonObject[i]) {
                contents += "<td class=\"border-right\">" + jsonObject[i][j] + "</td>";
            }
            contents += "</tr>";
            if(Math.round(i/tik) == i/tik) {
/* if I run the alert (between popups) i can see the progressbar update, otherwise I see no update, the progressbar appears empty then the $(container_id) element is updated with the table i've generated */
                alert(''); 
                $pb.progressbar("value",i/tik);
            }
        }
        var html = "<table cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"0\"><thead><tr>" + headers + "</tr></thead><tbody>" + contents + "</tbody></table>";

        $(container_id).html(html);
        $(container_id).children("table:first").dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sScrollX": "100%"
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded.  You'll have to break your work up into pieces and call them in sequence using "setTimeout" to allow the GUI to update during processing, but even then the browser will still seem somewhat unresponsive.

Comment: So am I better to just use an animated gif and not show the real progress?

Comment: @maerics: I thought asynchronous requests opened up a new thread?

Comment: First, use the loop to generate the HTML code. Then, (when the loop has finished), find the element on the page and update it.

Comment: @Šime Vidas, that would not show the 'progress' of the load...

Comment: The _alert()_ inturrupts the loop and the progress bar update is seen. Is there a way to _pause_ the loop without the _alert()_ so I can see the update?

Comment: @rlemon Then do what maerics said. Also, consider using [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_web_workers) which allow you do create a separate process which runs independently.

Comment: Perhaps you could show some kind of "loading" indicator before generating the html and then remove it after the html has been generated? It won't give an indication of how much it has loaded at any given time, but if it's only a few seconds, that may not matter too much?

Comment: @Anthony: true, the I/O operations for an XMLHttpRequest are handled in a separate thread by the browser but the JavaScript language is decidedly single threaded.  You can register callbacks (e.g. with "setTimeout", XMLHttpRequest handlers, etc.) but there is no multithreading (e.g. create/join/lock), as in other languages.

Comment: @rlemon: showing an infinite progress bar before you start your processing is certainly an easy solution, definitely worth trying to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: @maerics: lol, the loading gif "freezes" on a single pane while post callback is being run... fail... *sigh*

Comment: @rlemon: d'oh!  Let me guess only in IE?

Comment: @maerics: nope, FireFox 5.0.1 - didn't continue testing past that. FireFox and Chrome are required browsers. IE is optional. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**[Added my comment as an answer]**

JavaScript is single threaded. You'll have to break your work up into pieces and call them in sequence using "setTimeout" to allow the GUI to update during processing (in between your calls) but even then the browser will still seem somewhat unresponsive.

Comment: Actually the [web workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/workers.html) give a good alternative to the 'setTimeout' solution...

Comment: @revers: yes, WebWorkers seems to have been designed for exactly this kind of problem; however, it's an HTML5 draft (last time I checked) so newer browsers will have some support but there will be differences in behavior.  Older browsers will have to do something kludgey like I suggested.

Comment: Even leaving aside web workers, *JavaScript*, the language, has never been single-threaded. JavaScript is silent on the topic of threading, and even in 2011, multi-threaded environments were available (such as Rhino on the JVM, and a couple of NodeJS-like things that never took off -- multi-threaded programming is *hard*).

Answer (score 3):

You can try using WebWorker: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Worker
Thus worker are executed in parallel of the main thread, you cannot exactly achieve multi-threading using workers: you cannot modify the UI from a worker.
You can maybe create your grid as a string in a worker and when the worker finish, append it where you want.

Comment: Seems that their HTTP Secure is having issues.... cannot load any of the pages under https

Comment: You can also have a look at [this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-enviornment-subworkers) then. But as maerics mentions Web workers are quite new and are only supported by new browsers.

Answer (score 2):

If you do all the building of the Database in a setTimeout, the rest of the page should be responsive.

You can construct the html elements in that function, and when it is ready, attach it to the DOM. You will also have to call functions or send events to update the display of the progress bar.

**Edit after comment:**

This will run in background and won't affect responsiveness of the page:

`window.setTimeout(function() {buildDataTable(db_table, container_id)}, 0);`

You already update your progressbar from your function, so this should do it.

However, you might want to decouple the code generating the datatable from the code updating the progressbar.

Comment: Can you clerify this? wrap the function call in setTimeout(function(){ **Function Call** },0);

Comment: If buildDataTable is a longruning task (and OP says it is) then this approach will not solve the unresponsive UI problem as it will block while it's running (it just might allow something else just before it starts running).  You would need to break the task down into smaller chunks and call setTimeout for each of these to get some kind of timesharing.

Answer (score 1):

So it appears the only clean way to do this in my application is to process the json on the server and build the html there. **Then** return the html to the browser via `$.post()`

The progress bar will be lost. however I can use a infinite loading gif...