# Integrating two functions in Onclick. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Codepen Link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjVWwB

Hi, I want to know how two function can integrate in onClick function.

Please open the above codepen link.

INPUT DATA:

```
 &

<!-- <#assign SEMFirmNameAlt = " - ${site.data.SEMFirmNameAlt}">
<#if site.data.SEMFirmNameAlt = "">
    <#assign SEMFirmNameAlt = "">
</#if> -->
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
    &amp;

<#assign SEMFirmNameAlt = " - ${site.data.SEMFirmNameAlt}">
<#if site.data.SEMFirmNameAlt = "">
    <#assign SEMFirmNameAlt = "">
</#if>
```

Please note that it's a simple code conversion app which will take user's input data and process the input and give the EXPECTED OUTPUT.

First "&" conversion is working fine but unable to do the second uncomment part.

CODE FOR SECOND UNCOMMENT PART:

```
var comments = $("body").contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeName === "#comment"
    });
    $(comments[0]).replaceWith(function(){return document.createTextNode(this.data);});
```

Please comment below if you have any doubt regarding this question.

Answer (score 0):

Either do something like this (basically putting a semicolon after each function you want to do):

```
<input type="button" value="Process String" onclick="processString(); test();" style="width:250px" />
```

or:

```
function abc() {
 abcd();
 abcde();
}
```

and

```
<input type="button" value="Process String" onclick="abc()" style="width:250px" />
```

That would serve the same function as:

```
<input type="button" value="Process String" onclick="abcd(); abcde();" style="width:250px" />
```

I would personally perfer having functions to do multiple functions, but you can do this method as well.

Comment: Hi i've tried this method before.. but failed. No idea how on single click both function will work. Please open the codepen link. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Lipak, I'm a bit confused on what you were trying to ask so my apologies. Are you trying to do 2 things at the same time? Can you please explain better.

Comment: Yes.. exactly... two things should be achieved in only one Onclick function.

Comment: I'm not really sure there is a solution to doing 2 things at the same time, since JS is a single-threaded language. It requires having multiple threads to do things like that. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998330/how-to-do-threading-in-javascript. I believe there is some web-worker solution, I'll look more into that.

Comment: Thanks :) Please try to find any solution for this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a single function that calls both of those, and then use it in the event?

```
function myFunction(){
    pay();
    cls();
}
```

And then, for the button:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click" onclick="myFunction();"/>
```

Comment: I tried already... but failed dude.. can help me with this ? Please open the link above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input type="button" value="any value" onclick="function1(); function2();">
```

just seprate both function with (;)

Comment: I tried.. but failed. Can you help me with this... please open the codepen link.