# jquery, while loop running in the background, simultaneous while loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

1) How make that while loop would run in background, and the webpage would respond to user clicks despite while loop.
If I start the characters generating while loop, I am not able to input the data to the "input", because the generating loop occupies all resources. Actually, whenever I click "start", I am getting the message that the webpage is not responding asking if I want to stop it. After choosing "to stop", I see that the characters are generated. Nevertheless, it is very difficult to input the characters to the input field and to stop the program with "stop" trigger, and usually webpage crashes.

2) How to make several jquery while loops to run simultaneously, and additionally, webpage should be responsive and accessible to user.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<script src="theme/assets/js/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Start"> <b> Start </b> </div>
        <div id="Stop"> <b> Stop </b> </div>
        <br><br> <div id="random"> </div>
        <br><br>  <input id="input" type="text" size="500"> 

        <script>
// how to manage without global variables? how to pass variables to the function
        var flag = false;
        var charstr = "zxcvbnm,\.\/asdfghjkl;\'qwertyuiop[]\\`ąčęėįšųū90\-ž";
        var charstrL = charstr.length;

    $("#Start").click( function() {
        $("#lesson").text("clicked Start");
        flag =true;
        $(this).val('flag');
        while(flag){
            setInterval(function() { // this code is executed every 500 milliseconds:
                var rand = Math.random();
                var num =  Math.floor( ( Math.random() * (charstr.length -1) ) );
                $("#lesson").text(charstr[num]);
            }, 500);
        }//while
     }); // $("#Start").click( function() {

    $("#Stop").click( function(){
        flag=false;
        $(this).val('flag');
        alert('clicked Stop');
    }); 

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded.

Comment: @DrewKennedy: No, JavaScript isn't single-threaded. Not even on browsers. JavaScript, the *language*, is silent on the topic of threading; it's an environment thing. In browsers, there is one main UI thread, and as many web worker threads as you like.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [How to do Threading in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6998592/4204026) Granted this is from 2011, so if something has changed, I'd be more than happy to stand corrected

Comment: Who said you can't , you can use web workers for latest browsers 

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html

Comment: @DrewKennedy: That answer is incorrect. It was also incorrect in 2011. Moreover, there are already comments on it pointing out that it's incorrect.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ahh yes, missed the comments.

Comment: thank you for the comments about threading.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this with JSON?

Comment: Asynchronous javascript: https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a `while` loop run in the background if it's doing DOM manipulation, because there's only one main UI thread in browser JavaScript.

You also probably don't want to, because this code:

```
while (flag) {
    setInterval(function() { // this code is executed every 500 milliseconds:
    var rand = Math.random();
    var num =  Math.floor( ( Math.random() * (charstr.length -1) ) );
        $("#lesson").text(charstr[num]);
    }, 500);
}
```

continuously adds **additional** timers to call that code every 500ms. In a very short period of time, your browser will become completely non-responsive.

Just set up `setInterval`, and have the code inside decide whether to run based on `flag`:

```
setInterval(function() { // this code is executed every 500 milliseconds:
    if (flag) {
        var rand = Math.random();
        var num =  Math.floor( ( Math.random() * (charstr.length -1) ) );
        $("#lesson").text(charstr[num]);
    }
}, 500);
```

You *can* have several of those, though if you have a *lot* of them you might consider having fewer and just having them do more than one thing each time.

Comment: How to implement with while loop. I need constant generation after each 500ms

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this with JSON?

Comment: Dera Crowder, finally i understood what you wrote. There is no need for while in your example. Thank you so much.

Comment: Found [promises] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [p2] (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) , seems they enable multithreading in js, will write more when understand.

Comment: @olga: No, promises don't enable multi-threading in JavaScript, they just bring different (better) semantics to asynchronous operations. Multi-threading is an *environment* thing, not a language thing (in regard to JavaScript). For example: JavaScript on web browsers is multi-threaded if you use [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) (single-threaded if you don't), multi-threaded on the JVM (e.g., if you're using Rhino or Nashorn), and single-threaded on NodeJS; because that's how each of those environments sets it up.

Comment: @olga: Link-only comments don't actually say anything. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example for a program prompting user to input characters utilizing `setInterval` function instead of `while loop`. The application is to improve the typing skills.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<script src="theme/assets/js/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js">  </script>
    </head>
    <body>

<div id="Start"> <b> Start </b> </div> 

<br><div id="lesson"> </div>
<input id="input" type="text" size="500"> 

<span id="Stop">  Stop  </span>
<span id="Clear"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    Clear     </span>

        <script>
// how to manage without global variables ? how to pass vaiables to the function
        var flag = false;
        var charstr = "zxcvbnm,\.\/asdfghjkl;\'qwertyuiop[]\\`ąčęėįšųū90\-ž";
        var charstrL = charstr.length;

    $("#Start").click( function() {
        flag =true;
        $(this).val('flag');
        if(flag){
            setInterval( function() { // this code is executed every 500 milliseconds:
            if (flag) {
                var rand = Math.random();
                var num =  Math.floor( ( Math.random() * (charstr.length -1) ) );
                $("#lesson").text("\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0"+charstr[num]);
            } //if (flag) {
            }, 500);
        } // if (flag)
     }); // $("#Start").click( function() {     

    /*    
   // does not work, because creates infinite loops, each with 500ms waiting time. 
   // In miliseconds this accumulates to hours and thousands of loops generated usign while
        while(flag){
            setInterval(function() { // this code is executed every 500 milliseconds:
                var rand = Math.random();
                var num =  Math.floor( ( Math.random() * (charstr.length -1) ) );
                $("#lesson").text(charstr[num]);
            }, 500);
        }//while */

   //

    $("#Stop").click( function(){
        flag=false;
        $(this).val('flag');
    }); 


    $("#Clear").click( function(){
        $("#input").val(''); 
        $("#lesson").text(' '); 
    });     

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```